# Why is the matrix inverse the same as the change of basis matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

I have the question from my textbook,

> In $\mathbb{R}^2$, where
>
> $$D=\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}-2\\4\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle,$$
>
> find the change of basis matrices from $D$ to $\varepsilon_2$ and from $\varepsilon_2$ to $D$. Multiply the two.

My process was to represent the basis $D$ w.r.t.  $\varepsilon_2$ and vice versa. I got the matrices.

For example $Rep_D,\varepsilon_2(id)=\begin{pmatrix}2&-2\\1&4\end{pmatrix}$. However, the solution set showed that he just found the inverse matrix $$ Rep_D,\varepsilon_2(id)=(1/10)\begin{pmatrix}4&2\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4/10&2/10\\-1/10&2/10\end{pmatrix}$$
for the rep $\varepsilon_2$ w.r.t. $D$

My question is how does the representation from $\varepsilon_2$ w.r.t. $D$ the same as the inverse of the representation from the rep of $D$ w.r.t. $\varepsilon_2$? Are they not technically viewing the same vector from "$2$ different perspectives"? How is one just the inverse of the other?

Thank you!

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: It's from Jim Hefferon's Linear Algebra book, Pg. 265, Question 1.7.

Comment: Thank you. I think there's another e in his name . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\varepsilon_2$ refers to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$. Let $d_1,d_2$ denote the vectors of $D$, and let $e_1,e_2$ denote the vectors of $\varepsilon e_2$.

Let $P$ denote the matrix for the change of basis from $D$ to $\varepsilon _2$, and let $Q$ denote the reverse change of basis. The purpose of the matrix $P$ is to be such that for any constants $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,$
$$
a_1 d_1 + a_2 d_2 = b_1 e_1 + b_2 e_2 \iff P \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}. \tag{1}
$$
The fact that the vectors $d_1,d_2$ are already presented relative to the basis $\varepsilon_2$ makes this easy. We find that
$$
a_1d_1 + a_2 d_2 =\\
a_1(1\cdot e_1 + 2 \cdot e_2) + a_2(-2\cdot e_1 + 4 \cdot e_2) =\\
(1\cdot a_1 + (-2)\cdot a_2)e_1  + (2\cdot a_1 + 4\cdot a_2)e_2.
$$
That is, the coordinates $(b_1,b_2)$ of the vector $a_1 d_1 + a_2 d_2$ relative to $\varepsilon_2$ are
$$
\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2} = \pmatrix{1\cdot a_1 + (-2)\cdot a_2\\2\cdot a_1 + 4\cdot a_2} = \pmatrix{1&-2\\2&4}\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2}.
$$
So, we see that $P = \pmatrix{1&-2\\2&4}$. Note that each $d_1$ becomes a column of $P$.

On the other hand, the purpose of $Q$ is to be such that for any constants $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$,
$$
a_1 d_1 + a_2 d_2 = b_1 e_1 + b_2 e_2 \iff \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = Q\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}. \tag{2}
$$
Note the similarity between conditions (1) and (2). In other word, we're looking for a matrix $Q$ such that
$$
\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = Q \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2} \iff P\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}.
$$
Now, it isn't hard to see that the matrix $P^{-1}$ has this property. Indeed,
$$
P\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2} \iff\\
P^{-1}P\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = P^{-1}\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2} \iff\\
\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = P^{-1}\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}.
$$
So, we should find that $Q = P^{-1}$.